# Problem debug react apps with visual code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Is it possible for Visual Code to show me exactly in which line of my program there is an error? In the image, it only shows me the text of the error, but dosen't  show where it occurs in my program.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAwQA.png)

I tried change the file launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
             "outputCapture": "std",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "skipFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/<node_internals>/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: On the right in the white writing you can generally find the line with the error or at least something functionally related. In this case it's properUnstyled.js line 94.

Comment: Yes, but it's not my code. it show problem with component, but i want know where is the problem in my code without manual searching.